Using Windows.Services.Store on flutter Windows App
I have a Flutter Windows App on the Windows Store called "Save the Umfths".  I am trying to offer a free trial but looks like the only way to determine if the App installed is a trial is to use the Windows.Services.Store library. Is there a way to include this library with a Flutter Windows app so I can call the necessary function to determine trial status?  Is there any other way to achieve this?
